# Average_vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, vector, stl

I am working on generating average from vectors and having the avg as the vector outputs.

for example,

```
1 2 3
2 2 5
4 4 1
```

This will return to

```
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
3 3 3
```

However, when working with my code below, I get

> part2.cpp:48:2: error: no matching function for call to 'print_vector'
>          print_vector(&xVector);
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>   part2.cpp:15:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion >from
>        'std::vector > *' to 'std::vector > &'
>        for 1st argument; remove &
>   void print_vector(std::vector >& xVector)
>       ^

I dont know which part is the problem.
Also, I feel like the algorithm that is necessary for the averaging the vectors is related to double loop and just want to make sure if the logic and code are correct.

*I have a function that populates the vector in another cpp file.

```
void print_vector(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& xVector)
{
        for(int y = 0; y < xVector.size(); ++y)
        {
                for(int x = 0; x < xVector[y].size(); ++x)
                        cout << xVector[y][x] << " ";

                cout << endl;
        }
}

void average_vector(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& xVector)
{
    int sum;
    int avg;
    for(int y = 0; y < xVector.size(); ++y)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < xVector[y].size(); ++x)
        {
             sum += xVector[y][x];
             if(x == xVector[y].size())
             {
                 avg = sum / xVector[y].size();
                 for(int z = 0; z < xVector.size(); ++z)
                 {
                     for(int a = 0; a < xVector[z].size(); ++a)
                     {
                         xVector[a][z] = avg;
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    print_vector(&xVector);
}
```

Comment: `print_vector(&xVector)` should be `print_vector(xVector)`.

Comment: use `print_vector(xVector);`

Comment: [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: It clearly says "remove &" in the error message. Can you read?

Comment: BTW, your average will have rounding problem.

Comment: `if(x == xVector[y].size())` this condition will never be satisfied after `for(int x = 0; x < xVector[y].size(); ++x)`

Comment: Sorry for not seeing & part, but still the average function does not work..

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments have sufficiently addressed you issues with the error, so this is addressed to your question about your algorithm. You'll want to iterate over each value in a 2d vector, so nesting a loop in a loop is a pretty natural way of doing it. It should be something like this:

```
int sum, avg;
for(int y = 0; y < xVector.size(); y++) {
    sum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < xVector[y].size(); x++) {
        sum += xVector[y][x];
    }
    avg = sum / (float) xVector[y].size();
    for(int x = 0; x < xVector[y].size(); x++) {
        xVector[y][x] = avg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 5}, {4, 4, 1 }};

auto flat = v | ranges::view::join;
auto total = ranges::accumulate(flat, 0);
auto count =  flat.size();

for (auto& e : flat) {
    e = total / count;
    total -= e;
    --count;
}
print_vector(v);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4598197adb2f1b7e)